# How to hide documents at the CouchDb?

Tags: security, couchdb, cloudant

Is there any possibility at CouchDB or Cloudant to hide documents for users?

1. I have 2 Member roles `roleA` and `roleB` assigned to the users.
2. I have a database with 3 documents created by these users: `docA`, `docB`, `docC`

All these documents could be viewed by `_all_docs` view by default

I need to have a maintainable and scalable solution to hide documents.

For example:

a) Documents `docA` and `docC` should be available to view by users with `roleA` only

b) Documents `docB` and `docC` should be available to view by users with `roleB` only

c) Admins could see everything

I have reviewed an official documentation, best practices and other similar topics, but I can't find any scalable solution for this task

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all in CouchDB, the `_all_docs` view is a built-in view that allows you to retrieve a list of all documents in a database.
By default, any authenticated user with read access to the database can query the `_all_docs` view.

Also CouchDB doesn't inherently provide a feature for hiding documents, you can implement security measures to control access **only for editing** documents based on user roles and permissions using `validate_doc_update` function at the `_design` document

For example:

```json
"validate_doc_update": "function (newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {
  if (userCtx.roles.indexOf('roleA') === -1) throw({
    forbidden: 'Only users with roleA can edit documents!'
  });
  return;
}"
```

One more poor situation is how to debug these functions in case we have more complex logic.

Comment: This should be an edit to your question perhaps, not an accepted answer.